# Why does slicing decrease capacity by one

Tags: go, slice

So I was testing slices and thought that go won't decrease the capacity.  But from what i see it does.  Does anyone know the reason for the drop in capacity of 1?   `(go version go1.8 linux/amd64)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    name := make([]int, 0, 100000000)
    fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name), len(name))
    for x:= 0; x < 1000; x++ {
        name = append(name, x)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name), len(name))
    name2 := name[1:500]
    fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name2), len(name2))
}
```

The output is

```
100000000 | 0
100000000 | 1000
99999999 | 499
```

Changing the size to 1000 changes the output to this

```
1000 | 0
1000 | 1000
999 | 499
```

Comment: Indexing starts with 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you shrink a slice from the left (increasing the slice's start index in the underlying array), you reduce its capacity, because it can never grow to the left. When you shrink a slice from the right (reducing the slice's length), the capacity is unchanged, because a slice *can* grow to the right. For example:

```
name := make([]int, 100)
fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name), len(name))
name2 := name[:50]  // Won't shrink because left side is unchanged
fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name2), len(name2))
name2 = name[50:]   // WILL shrink because left side is moved up
fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name2), len(name2))
```

Outputs:

```
cap 100 | len 100
cap 100 | len 50
cap 50 | len 50
```

Playground demo: https://play.golang.org/p/jbGRmexV5d-

Answer (score 4):

By changing your code to the following (starting at index 0), then the capacity is unchanged inline with what you expected.  By using index 1 in the slice you have lost the first item (item at 0) which is why there is an apparent capacity change.

```
  name2 := name[0:500]
  fmt.Printf("%d | %d\n", cap(name2), len(name2))
```

Producing the output:

```
100000000 | 500
```

Comment: Totally make sense!  Thanks